# error loading project in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex4, ubuntu-14.04

i am getting an error while loading flex project on eclipse luna-java. Please help to solve this problem. I googled for rectify but i failed.
a problem occurred when opening project"zz". Try quitting and restarting the application. If the problem persists you might be using an unsupported project version, or your project files might be corrupted.

Comment: How did you "load" it ? Can you be more specific about the error ? any log in `workspace_location/.metadata/.log`?

Comment: !ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2015-05-20 11:21:39.692
!MESSAGE Error creating actionscript project for zz
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error Loading Project
        at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscript.internal.ActionScriptProject.createCoreException(ActionScriptProject.java:1616)
        at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscript.internal.ActionScriptProject.loadDescription(ActionScriptProject.java:514)
        at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscript.internal.ActionScriptProject.<init>(ActionScriptProject.java:183)
 this  i found  in log page